# Trying to start app.js with node

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

It gives me this error

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ node app.js

module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/pi/app.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:902:3
```

Also when I run Chromium in kiosk mode it give me this error

```
(chromium:2288): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? You can only run a file if it exists.

Comment: `cd /where/your/app.js/exists/`

Comment: @ChiChou, And for the other error?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745740/gtk-warning-cannot-open-display-when-running-a-gtkmm-project-in-eclipse